# Is there a was to conditionally style last n <li> elements with CSS alone?

Tags: html, css

Initially I have set the li style to

```
li.s {
  color: red;
}
```

below is the list :

```
<ul>
  <li class="s">First element</li>
  <li class="r">Second element</li>
  <li class="s">Third element</li>
  <li class="s">First element</li>
  <li class="r">Second element</li>
  <li class="s">Third element</li>
  <li class="s">Third element</li>
  <li class="r">Second element</li>
  <li class="s">Third element</li>
  <li class="s">Second element</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to know if there is any way to change the color of last 'n' li elements with class "s" ?

Comment: In css you've got `nth-child` and`nth-of-type`, but nothing like `nth-of-class` I'm afraid...

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for
You can read more about it here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

```
li:last-child {
      color: red;
    }
```